# How to plot thousands of solar system locations on a canvas via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object with ~8000 objects which are locations.  Each location has a positions object with x, y and z coordinates which looks like this:

```
"position": {
  "x": -103300968263126460,
  "y": 41707503568269944,
  "z": -29856304129795090
}
```

I've attempted several methods with no success.  Every viable solution I can find is a graph, and this is not a graph -- it is a map.  A map of solar systems, to be more precise.

Does anyone have any suggestions or know of a library that can handle building a map with this data?

Edit:  Here's some JS I put together which plots everything using x and y coords:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var systems = '../js/json/eveSystems.json';

    $.getJSON(systems, function(data) {

        data.forEach(function(systemData) {
            var x = systemData.position.x.toString();
            var y = systemData.position.y.toString();

            if (x.indexOf('-') > -1) {
                var coordX = x.substr(0,4);
            } else {
                var coordX = x.substr(0,3);
            }

            if (y.indexOf('-') > -1) {
                var coordY = y.substr(0,4);
            } else {
                var coordY = y.substr(0,3);
            }

            $('#center').append('<div class="point" id='+systemData.name+' style="margin-top: '+coordY+'px; margin-left:'+coordX+'px;"></div>');
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the CodePen:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdQexX

Comment: This will probably be closed as too broad or asking for an off–site resource. You need to [transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations) the x,y coordinates (pretty sure you can ignore z unless you're using a perspective view) from whatever system you're using to cartesian coordinates of your canvas based on its size in whatever units you're using, probably pixels. Why not just use Google Maps?

Comment: @Tigger—the phrase "*A map of solar systems…*" could mean terrestrial installations of solar power systems or astronomic solar systems (like the one the Earth is in). :-)

Comment: @RobG : Haha, Yep, I think I miss-read that. In that case I would look for the open source project that "Sky Map" was built on. (I think) this was a Google Project that was released many years back.

Comment: Up voted for the idea flagged for the format

Comment: Thanks for the comments and apologies for the lack of code.  I've added a CodePen with my current method.  As you'll see there's a large gap from my origin point which I'm not sure how to best remove.

Comment: Those are seriously large numbers. May I suggest first dividing them by 10 trillion (10000000000000) to get them to manageable size that has a chance of being relevant to page coordinates?

Comment: Also, I've worked with something like this before (drawing large family trees) and I strongly recommend that you should not care about negative coordinates. The DOM can handle negative coordinates fine and you can draw in a div then allow the users to pan the div (like google maps) by manipulating it's offsetTop and offsetLeft or margins